# cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Activity in which i m getting the results from XML via Async task. This is my code of the activity from which i am getting the prediction

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prediction);

    Past = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Present = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Future = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    new GetPrediction().execute();

}       

class GetPrediction extends AsyncTask <Void, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Prediction.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Getting your fortune");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            URL website = new URL(baseUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            HandlingXMLReading doingWork = new HandlingXMLReading(); // created object of default handler class
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
           past = doingWork.getPastPrediction();
           present = doingWork.getPresentPrediction();
           future = doingWork.getFuturePrediction();

    } 
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            past = e.getMessage();
            present = e.getMessage();
            future = e.getMessage();
            }
        return past;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Past.setText(result);
        Present.setText(present);
        Future.setText(future);
    }

}

}
```

Now this works fine, but the problem is when this Async task call the Default handler class It gives me the above error.
In default handler class I made an object of a class from which I am getting some numbers.
I am using that numbers to parse the XML.
But when I removed That class object the code works fine.
Here is the code of HandleXMLData.class

```
public class HandlingXMLReading extends DefaultHandler {

// setting up the opbject
XMLDataCollection prediction = new XMLDataCollection();

/*These next 4 lines  gives the error of 
 * cannot create the handler inside thread
 */
SelectionFuture CardNo = new SelectionFuture();
int PastCard = CardNo.pastCardNo;
int PresentCard = CardNo.presentCardNo;
int FutureCard = CardNo.FutureCardNo;


/* Method Containing the Past Prediction*/
public String getPastPrediction()
{
    return prediction.Past();
}

/* Method Containing the Present Prediction*/
public String getPresentPrediction()
{
    return prediction.Present();
}

/* Method Containing the Past Prediction*/
public String getFuturePrediction()
{
    return prediction.Future();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);


     if (localName.equals("overview_prediction1")){
            String past = attributes.getValue("name");
            prediction.setPast(past);
            }

 if (localName.equals("overview_prediction2")){
        String present  = attributes.getValue("name");
        prediction.SetPresent(present);
        }

     if (localName.equals("overview_prediction3")){
        String future = attributes.getValue("name");
        prediction.SetFuture(future);
        }

}}
```

I am not able to understand what is happening.
Thanks In advance

Comment: may be it is happening because i am calling a object of a class which have the working UI thread. But i want the values of the card so that i putup those numbers in the localname for XML parsing

Comment: Try moving your `HandlingXMLReading` instance outside the `AsyncTask` thread. Instantiate it in a class constructor of your `GetPrediction` class.

Comment: can you please edit this piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` internally uses a `Handler`. A `Handler` basically allows you to post `Runnables` from another thread on the thread the handler was assigned to, which in the case of `AsyncTask` is always the thread from which it is called.
so simplest method is creating object for your handler in void `onCreate()`,instead of creating object inside of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This might solve your problem

```
private HandlingXMLReading doingWork;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prediction);

    Past = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Present = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Future = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    doingWork = new HandlingXMLReading(); // created object of default handler class

    new GetPrediction().execute();

}       

class GetPrediction extends AsyncTask <Void, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Prediction.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Getting your fortune");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            URL website = new URL(baseUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            past = doingWork.getPastPrediction();
            present = doingWork.getPresentPrediction();
            future = doingWork.getFuturePrediction();

    } 
        catch( Exception e)
        {
            past = e.getMessage();
            present = e.getMessage();
            future = e.getMessage();
            }
        return past;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Past.setText(result);
        Present.setText(present);
        Future.setText(future);
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not working neil.. Even I have also tried this the same. earlier..
it gives Null in Strings

Comment: Are you still getting the cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare() issue?

Comment: No.. That issue is resolved but i cant get the values in strings fron methods inside the HandleXMLclass

Comment: That is a different issue then.

Comment: @ kevin I have to call these values in the Default handler Class.
if the add this code `SelectionFuture CardNo = new SelectionFuture();
int PastCard = CardNo.pastCardNo;
int PresentCard = CardNo.presentCardNo;
int FutureCard = CardNo.FutureCardNo;` in default handler class then the class is not compiling even..
how can I achieve to call these values in Default handler class